# Power on machine when there is power?

Tags: hardware, electrical-power

Is there a solution for powering a machine back on after power loss once the power is back on? I could use wake-on-lan, but if there is a solution (software or hardware) to automatically power-up once there is power again it would fit a bit better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the time, there is a BIOS option for what to do when getting power back. You can set it to "Always on" or "Last State" or "Never power on" (or something like that).
I prefer the second one.

Answer (score 3):

usually available as a setting in the BIOS setup